# Python regex to remove substrings inside curly braces

Tags: python, regex

I have a line which has lots of words and characters. I just want to remove the part which is included in  double curly braces

```
{{ }}
```

I tried `?={{.*}}` but I am not getting anything.

Comment: Can you have nested curly braces?

Comment: That's because Python doesn't deal with curly braces.  See `from __future__ import braces`

(I'm kidding, for anyone new to Python)

Comment: So it is nested but between two consecutive braces are continuous and nothing in between them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
s = re.sub('{{.*?}}', '', s)
```

Note that `{` and `}` are usually special characters in regular expressions and should usually be escaped with a backslash to get their literal meaning. However in this context they are interpreted as literals.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/EzQJJ)

Comment: Note that the second argument in `re.sub(...)` can be passed a function to. This function will be called for each substitution with a matches object. The returned string from this function will be the replacement for that substitution.

This might be useful when processing variables in a string, or things alike.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to extract the text from inside the curly braces, try something like:

```
import re 
s = 'apple {{pear}} orange {banana}'
matches = re.search(r'{{(.*)}}', s)
print matches.group(1)
```

`group(1)` will contain the string 'pear'

Comment: I Want to remove them from the existing line

Comment: hence this matching wont help in my case