# Python regular expression search doesn't works on a string contains colon(:)

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which can be like "some string {{key:value}} again some string {{key:value}}{{key:value}} some string"
I want to find all the {{key:value}} matching sub strings from the given string. for this what pattern I am trying is like :

```
string ="fdfd{{dsfdss:dssssasa}} fdsfdsfds"
pattern = re.compile("\\\\[a-z]\w+\:\[a-z]\w+\}}")
abc = re.search( pattern, string)
```

I tried it using this also

```
pattern = re.compile("\\\\[a-z]\w+:[a-zA-Z]\w+\}}")
abc = re.search( pattern, string)
```

But each time it is returning None

Suggested me the best way to accomplish it.

Comment: You are trying to match a ``\`` with your regex but it is missing in the input.

Comment: What is with the leading \\\\? And you never grab the open curly brace

Comment: Do want to only "Key" and "value" from the dict?

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html about which escapes you need: You need to escape `{` and `}`, but not `[`. `\w` matches too much (also `:`).

Comment: Yes @Mayur Kostri, i want to grab the only key value pair from the string. it will be like "{{key:value}}" or [(key, value), (key, value)].

Comment: @SajidAhmad: Cyrbil's answer is correct and yields what you requested above (`[(key, value), ...]`). See [this demo](https://ideone.com/aXIT5T). Just remove the outer parentheses.

Comment: @stribizhev , the link you given works but fails when string is changed to string = u'fdfd{{dsfdss:dssssasa}} fdsfdsfds {{aaaa:bbbb}}'
in this case it returns an empty strng

Comment: @SajidAhmad: Are you sure? [I have not noticed any bug like that.](https://ideone.com/Lf3cym)

Comment: yes, it works this time, don't know why i got the null value at that time. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this simple regex:

```
({{(\w+):(\w+)}})
```

It returns the full match and elements:

> MATCH 1
>   1.  [4-23]  `{{dsfdss:dssssasa}}`
>   2.  [6-12]  `dsfdss`
>   3.  [13-21] `dssssasa`

Try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/rG2tT9/1)

**Python code:**

```
import re
string = u'fdfd{{dsfdss:dssssasa}} fdsfdsfds'
pattern = re.compile(ur'({{(\w+):(\w+)}})')
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

Edit:
For only the inner part, the regex is `{{(\w+:\w+)}}`

Comment: Fun fact: you can remove extra backslashes and use `({{(\w+):(\w+)}})`. Python re module is still a bit smart and unlike Java recognizes the `{` not followed by a digit and closing brace is a literal `{`. And `}` do not have to be escaped.

Comment: Thank you, but why is that possible ? Is it because the regex engine understand that it is not a quantifier ? How ?

Comment: Ok, you edit your answer and answered my interrogation :)

Comment: Hi @Cybril, thanks for your answer. It works also but what i need is a bit different. I need only the text enclosed in {{}}.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @SajidAhmad ? Just `dsfdss:dssssasa` ?

Comment: @SajidAhmad: It is even easier then, and your question is a practically a dupe of [*regex in python dealing with curly braces*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643553/regex-in-python-dealing-with-curly-braces): use `{{(.*?)}}` with `re.findall`.

Comment: yes, I need only this key value pair, not other strings.

Comment: Move the parenthesis a bit ... `{{(\w+:\w+)}}` you could have figure that by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\{\{([^\:]+)\:([^\}]+)\}\}
```