# Python regex to find all case of curly brackets, inclusive of brackets

Tags: python, regex

I would to like find and replace strings within double curly brackets, inclusive of the brackets themselves.

For example:

```
<a href="#">{{hello}}</a>
```

should ideally return:

```
{{hello}}
```

I found this expression: `{{(.*?)}}` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643553/python-regex-to-remove-substrings-inside-curly-braces)

However this only returns text *between* the brackets. Ie. With this expression, the example above would return: `"hello"`, rather than `"{{hello}}"`

Comment: Where is this input HTML coming from and why exactly do you need the element texts in double curly braces? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move the `(` and `)` to include the brackets within the group.

Try: `({{.*?}})`. I highly recommend a [regex tester](http://regexr.com/) for this kind of work.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using `re.findall()` which only returns the contents of capturing groups, if they are present in the regex.

Since you don't want them, just remove the capturing parentheses:

```
matches = re.findall("{{.*?}}", mystring)
```

When using `re.sub()` for replacing, the original regex will work just fine.